# How to use str methods inside pandas query()

Tags: python, string, pandas

There appears to be a right and a wrong way to use str methods inside of pandas query. Why is the first query working as expected but the second one fails:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> data = {'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'],
    ...         'year': [2012, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2014],
    ...         'coverage': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame(data, index = ['Cochice', 'Pima', 'Santa Cruz', 'Maricopa', 'Yuma'])
>>> print(df.query('name.str.slice(0,1)=="J"'))
              coverage   name  year
    Cochice         25  Jason  2012
    Maricopa        62   Jake  2014
>>> 
>>> print(df.query('name.str.startswith("J")'))
<lines omitted>
    TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Comment: Strange.. I copied your exact code and it works fine. Did you do something to manipulate the original df?

Comment: @AndrewL, what is your Pandas version? I could reproduce this error (`df.query('name.str.startswith("J")')`) using Pandas 0.19.2 and 0.20.1

Comment: Interesting- also 0.19.2 running on mac, however.

Comment: My environment: Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:52:12)

Comment: @AndrewL, this is interesting! What `numexpr` version  `pd.show_versions()` shows?

Comment: @MaxU `None` ! Is this normal?

Comment: @AndrewL, aha! That explains why it worked for you. If `numexpr` is not installed Pandas does `df.query(" ... ", engine='python')`. Default engine is `numexpr`, which should be faster for numerical operations

Comment: @MaxU Fascinating and great to know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this trick:

```
In [62]: df.query("name.str.startswith('J').values")
Out[62]:
          coverage   name  year
Cochice         25  Jason  2012
Maricopa        62   Jake  2014
```

alternatively you can specify `engine='python'`:

```
In [63]: df.query("name.str.startswith('J')", engine='python')
Out[63]:
          coverage   name  year
Cochice         25  Jason  2012
Maricopa        62   Jake  2014
```

**Timing:** for 500K rows DF:

```
In [68]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [69]: df.shape
Out[69]: (500000, 3)

In [70]: %timeit df.query("name.str.startswith('J')", engine='python')
1 loop, best of 3: 583 ms per loop

In [71]: %timeit df.query("name.str.startswith('J').values")
1 loop, best of 3: 587 ms per loop

In [72]: %timeit df[df.name.str.startswith('J')]
1 loop, best of 3: 571 ms per loop

In [74]: %timeit df.query('name.str.slice(0,1)=="J"')
1 loop, best of 3: 482 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks you @MaxU. Adding engine='python' does the trick. I wonder why you need it for str.startswith but not for str.slice.

Comment: @CarlosE, i think it has something to do with the `numexpr`, which is the default engine for `DataFrame.query()`